# Выдает ошибку спустя время

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

```
C:\Users\kudro>"C:\Users\kudro\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\bot\bot.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kudro\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\bot\bot.py", line 97, in <module>
    sender(id, "Такой команды нет!\n Напиши «меню»", clear_key)
  File "C:\Users\kudro\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\bot\bot.py", line 9, in sender
    vk_session.method('messages.send', {'user_id' : id, 'message' : text, 'random_id' : 0, 'keyboard' : key})
  File "C:\Users\kudro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\vk_api\vk_api.py", line 668, in method
    raise error
vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [901] Can't send messages for users without permission
```

Выдает такую  ошибку, только в одной группе. В других  группах  все работают. Но  ошибка  спустя  секунд  20. Код  могу  скинуть.

[Настройки  группы](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oM2Y.jpg)

[image: настройки группы 2][image: настройки группы]

Comment: могу скинкть  еще  скрины

Answer (score 0):

901 - Пользователь запретил отправку сообщений от имени сообщества. Это значит, либо пользователь запретил получать сообщения от группы, либо ещё не писал в неё. Если, пользователь ВКонтакте не написал сообщение в группу, значит он и не может получать их, так как это скорее всего как анти-спам.